# Bounded similarity measure for points in hyperbolic space

Tags: inner-products, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

given two points $x, y$ on an n-sphere (embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$, their inner product $\langle x, y \rangle = x_1y_1 + \dots + x_{n+1}y_{n+1}$ will be a scalar in $[-1, 1]$ which can be interpreted as the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between the two points.

What would be an equivalent measure for points in a hyperbolic space?
The Minkowski inner product looks like a good starting point, but I have no idea how to properly convert it to a bounded similarity measure.

(sorry if the description isn't extremely formal, I hope I was clear enough)

Thanks

Comment: I would say that the Minkowski inner product *is* the equivalent measure. Just as the inner product can be interpreted as the cosine similarity, the Minkowski inner product can be interpreted as the hyperbolic cosine similarity. Cosine similarity goes from 1 to -1 while the hyperbolic cosine similarity goes from 1 to $\infty$, just as the functions "cos" and "cosh" themselves. If you want it bounded, you can take the inverse, but I think this makes it a bit less equivalent.

Comment: Other possibilities are the distance between $x$ and $y$, and the (Minkowski) "interval" $\langle x-y,x-y \rangle$. All three values have the property that they are a (anti-)monotonic function of the distance. In my application I use the interval as the measure of similarity, because it is easy to compute and it generalizes to Euclidean too (cosine similarity is a bit easier to compute, but it does not generalize to Euclidean).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try to work with $\langle x-y, x-y \rangle$ and see what happens.